# Open Multiple gvims but open one after closing the previous one

Tags: linux, bash, vim, terminal

I have three files named `one.txt`, `two.txt`, `three.txt`.

I've made a file `dummy` which contains:

```
gvim one.txt
gvim two.txt
gvim three.txt
```

Here, when I source `dummy`, it opens all the 3 files simultaneously.

What I intend is to open `two.txt` only when I close `one.txt`, and open `three.txt` only when I close `two.txt` and so on.

What modification should I do in dummy to make it work as expected?

Comment: Add `&&` at the end of each line but the last.

Comment: @pmf Doesn't help. `gvim` automatically detaches itself from the terminal/shell so `&&` does nothing — all three windows open at once, not one after another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `-f` to mean foreground :

```
gvim -f one.txt
gvim -f two.txt
gvim -f three.txt
```

Comment: this works as expected. thanks